# Outputting php json data

Tags: json

I have a small problem when I get old messages from my database. I can't use the information using the usual `console.log(data.message);` because this comes back undefined but when I use `console.log(data);`

```
[{"message":"Hello","time":{"sec":1328831312,"usec":699000},"user":"4f326ef17edae18d11000000"},{"message":"Heyyy","time":{"sec":1328831324,"usec":48000},"user":"4f33a3db7edae17736000000"},{"message":"afasfasd","time":{"sec":1328831966,"usec":960000},"user":"4f33a3db7edae17736000000"},{"message":"asdfasdfasdf","time":{"sec":1328831968,"usec":283000},"user":"4f33a3db7edae17736000000"},{"message":"old message","time":{"sec":1328831969,"usec":234000},"user":"4f33a3db7edae17736000000"}]
```

I search my database for the messages between two users and then loop through the data like this

```
$messages = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($cursor['messages']); $i++){
    $object = array('message'=>$cursor['messages'][$i]['message'],
                    'time'=>$cursor['messages'][$i]['time'],
                    'user'=>$cursor['messages'][$i]['user']);

    $messages[] = $object;
}
echo json_encode($messages)
```

I want to be able to get the users ID, message and time the message was sent so that I can append each to my chat history but I can stuck on outputting the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your response is contained within an array `[]`.

Assuming your paste is representative you should be able to get the data you want with

```
data[i].message
```

and

```
data[i].time.sec
```

etc.

In your JS you will want to loop up to data.length to retrieve each message.

**Edit**: Looks like you're not parsing the string after receiving it. Please try the following

```
var parsedData;
if(JSON && JSON.parse) {
    parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
}
else {
    parsedData = eval(data); 
}

alert(parsedData[0].message);
```

Comment: I haven't got any luck trying that, I don't know how to remove the wrapping array because of the way I collect the information in PHP I added the PHP above

Comment: @jamcoupe sorry removing the array is not a good option, I just re-read your question. The answer is updated on this point.

Comment: @jamcoupe are you actually deserializing the text output when you receive it in JS? The output you pasted is the same structure as if I test `console.log('[{"message": "hello"}]')` - this is just plain text and needs parsing before using as an object

Comment: The return value for data.length is like 483 so in the for loop i wrote `console.log(data[i]);` and the data.length represents every single character...

Comment: ahhhh yeah I hadn't serialized the output.

Comment: @jamcoupe ahh good stuff, I only saw this comment after I added that part to the answer